# 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<Player.Player: 0x7fcd6898aa00> should have parent view controller:

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Why does this error occur on Xcode 11 simmulator and not on iPad mini adhoc where it runs smoothly? The following output is spit out in the debugger after crashing. Also, how can it be fixed?

`'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<Player.Player: 0x7fcd6898aa00> should have parent view controller:<Cards.DetailViewController: 0x7fcd67d781e0> but actual parent is:<Superapps.PlayerViewController: 0x7fcd67d67490>'`

***Debugger Output***

...
[image]

```
***PlayerViewController.Swift***

//  PlayerViewController.Swift 


import UIKit
import Cards

let videoUrl = URL(string: "")!
let localUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "My Movie 14", withExtension: "mp4")



class PlayerViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var card: CardPlayer!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //btn rounded corners
    btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    btn.clipsToBounds = true
    
    card.videoSource = localUrl
    card.shouldDisplayPlayer(from: self)    //Required.
    
    card.playerCover = UIImage(named: "rainbow!")!  // Shows while the player is loading
    card.playImage = UIImage(named: "logo (1) copy.png")!  // Play button icon
    
    card.isAutoplayEnabled = false
    card.shouldRestartVideoWhenPlaybackEnds = true
    
    card.title = "Superapps!"
    //watch our commercial to learn more
    card.subtitle = ""
    card.category = "Professional Ecommerce Apps!"

    let cardContent = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CardContent5")
    card.shouldPresent(cardContent, from: self)
    
}


}
```

How can this be solved? After doing some search on stack overflow, it seems the fix should have a custom solution involving some code.

***Update***

When the following two lines of swift are commented out, the app no longer crashes.

```
let cardContent =     storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CardContent5")
   
 card.shouldPresent(cardContent, from: self)
```

How can this code be modified to retain the functionality?

***Update 2***

Tried the below. The app doesn't crash, but the button doesn't load anything.

```
let cardContent = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CardContent5")
    
card.shouldPresent(cardContent, from:storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CardContent5"))
```

Comment: `shouldPresent(from:` doesn’t seem to make any sense. Apparently you want to `present` the controller.

Comment: The dependency being used is an installed cocoa pod. I'll see if I can update it with some native swift.

Comment: `shouldPresent` looks like a delegate method – which you usually should not call yourself and  – which expects to return a `Bool`. Custom methods starting with `should` and not expecting a `Bool` like `shouldDisplayPlayer` are highly misleading.